# How to model IR LED Diode in SPICE

Tags: diodes, spice, ltspice

How does one model an IR diode in SPICE?  Specifically, the TIL38.

Datasheet here: http://www.supermoduul.com/PDF/TIL38.pdf

I get it that `Is` needs to be found -  is this the same as `If` in the datasheet?

The diode apparently seems to work in reverse-bias mode.

Answer (score 1):

No, the specified \$I_F\$ is not the same as \$I_S\$. Also, this is an LED so it is usually used in the forward-bias mode rather than in reverse bias (like a photodiode detector).

There isn't much information on the data sheet that could be used to create a SPICE model. You have two points on the I/V relationship under forward bias: the forward voltage \$V_F\$ at 100 mA and at 1 A of forward current. You could create a piece-wise linear model to fit these points using a voltage source and an ideal resistor. Depending on what sort of simulations you intend to run, that might be enough.

If you want to simulate other effects, such as leakage current in reverse bias or a.c. behavior, then you need to get a proper SPICE model from the manufacturer.